# How do I get a new version of a xcdatamodel to appear in xcode?

Tags: core-data, model, mapping-model

Environment: xcode 3.2.1, document-based core-data application.

I have a document-based cocoa app which uses core data. I have made multiple versions of the data model Xcode shows a xcdatamodeld directory with multiple xcdatamodels (versions) that I made over time. (I also have the appropriate mapping models). All works fine, but now when I want to create a new version, xcode refuses to show the new xcdatamodel. The file is actually created; I can see it in the finder if I go into the xcdatamodeld package.

Has anyone run into this behaviour? Is there a fix? Perhaps my xcodeproj file is corrupted somehow?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. Believe it or not, this anomalous behaviour was caused by a bug in a Logitech scripting addition which was tickled by the fact that I am using Default Folder X!

Weird, but true.

All better now.